# Keras/Tf Custom Loss Function at the level of tensor entries

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to write a custom loss function in Keras that takes in a tensor of predicted values and then for each process it through another function before adding to the loss. Here is what this looks like. This is a complete code example, please look at the function sample_loss.

```
class AE():
    def __init__(self,inputSize=78,numNeurons = 50, latentSize=5,expSize = 10,batchSize = 1, activation="relu"):
        K.clear_session()

        self.inputSize = inputSize
        self.latentSize = latentSize
        self.activation = activation
        self.numNeurons = numNeurons
        self.expSize = expSize
        self.batchSize = batchSize

        self.encoder = self.createEncoder()
        self.decoder = self.createDecoder()
        self.filterModel = self.createFilterModel()
        self.AE = self.createAE()

    def sample_loss(self,y_pred ):

        loss = 0.0

        for j in tf.range(0,self.inputSize ,2):

            pt = y_pred[j:j+2]
            loss += K.sum(self.filterModel.predict(pt))

        return loss

    def createEncoder(self):
        # create the encoder
        xIn = Input(shape=(self.inputSize,), name="data_in")
        y_train = Input(shape=(self.latentSize,), name='y_train')

        x = Dense(self.numNeurons,activation=self.activation)(xIn)
        xlatent = Dense(self.latentSize,activation=self.activation)(x)

        # create the encoder
        encoder = Model(xIn,xlatent)
        return encoder

    def createDecoder(self):
        # create the decoder
        latentIn = Input(shape=(self.latentSize,))
        x = Dense(self.numNeurons,activation=self.activation)(latentIn)
        out = Dense(self.inputSize,activation="linear")(x)

        # create a decoder
        decoder = Model(latentIn,out)

        return decoder

    def createAE(self):
        xIn = Input(shape=(self.inputSize,), name="ae_data_in")

        # create the total model
        latentOutput = self.encoder(xIn)
        dataOutput = self.decoder(latentOutput)

        model = Model(inputs=xIn,outputs=dataOutput)
        model.add_loss( self.sample_loss( dataOutput) )

        model.summary()

        return model

    def createFilterModel(self):
        xIn = Input(shape=(2,), name="filter_data_in")

        x = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')(xIn)
        x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

        model = Model(xIn,x)
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

        return model


modelAE = AE()
modelAE.AE.compile(optimizer='adam',loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

So I have a dictionary of models, filterModels. These are actually predictive models in Keras. For each model in this dictionary, I want to pass it the corresponding part of y_pred and then add its output to the loss.

How can I do this?

Here is the error the current code gives me:
'''
ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 78)
'''

Comment: Is it `tf2`? what is `expSize`?  what is `inputSize`? how does `i` relate to `j` when you seem to be mixing tensor size with number of models? Please describe what you want to do in detail.

Comment: Think of it as a matrix, expSize is the rows, inputSize is the columns. For each row, take 2 consecutive points and input them into a filter function. Take that output and add it to your loss.

Comment: Did you try your function, did it work? What went wrong? It seems ok as long as you replace `.predict(pt)` with `(pt, training=False)`.

Comment: You just don't need the `i` loop at all.

Comment: When I add training=False I get: tf__predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'training'

Comment: Is it not tensorflow 2?

Comment: When I run it without, it asks me to decorate it with @tf.function. Then I get the following error: ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect thetensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 78)

Comment: crap its not. I thought it was upgraded. I guess 2 would be better for this?

Comment: Not sure, there are different ways of doing it, but the last error you wrote is definitely strange.....it should never expect static batch sizes, unless you manually defined it as static (which is usually bad). --- But you're the third person today that seems to present something related to strange batch size behaviors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208714/discussion-between-madprogrammer-and-daniel-moller).